# Blazor - restoring multiple dependent dropdown lists with localstorage OnAfterRenderAsync

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

i have 3 dropdown lists in my blazor server side app. the second dropdown is dependent on the choice of the first one and the third one is dependent on the choice of the second one.

i'm loading the list of the first one in the OnInitializedAsync() method.
in the OnAfterRenderAsync() method i fetch the data from localStorage and then i load the lists of the second and third dropdown.

when i debug my code, everything works fine but when i just run the application, sometimes it only fills the first one or the first and the last one. it seems like the localstorage fetch is too slow in some cases. i added a Task.Delay to test and this seems to solve the issue on my PC but when i deploy this to our IIS server this does not work.

is there a proper way to solve this?

```
        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                if (localStorage != null)
                {
                    if (await localStorage.ContainKeyAsync("planningFilter"))
                    {
                        planningFilter = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<PlanningFilter>("planningFilter");
                        HalLijst = await abService.GetActieveHallen(planningFilter.VestigingId);
                        MachineLijst = await abService.GetActieveMachines(planningFilter.HalId);
                        //await Task.Delay(2000);
                        StateHasChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to have it depend on the change event of the parent. [Here's an example](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/319/cascading-dropdowns-with-blazor). There's even more delay when calling back end APIs so hopefully that works out for you.